# How to login via wordpress api and get user details?

Tags: api, rest-api

I want to login via wordpresss api. I tried with "/wp-json/wp/v2/users" . but it just returns user 1 details.

My goal is login via api and fetch all profile information.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Install  and activate [JWT Authentication for WP REST API plugin](https://pt.wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/), also install  [WP REST API plugin](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API) 
 **2.** Now you can run any wordpress default api from mobile app or any other source or by postman. for example hit this url from your app or by postman. https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts 
 **3.** By app or by postman, When you will login with valid details (using rest api) you will get back a token. To login and get token, run the following url by postman or by app
 https://example.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token
 
 **4.** By this way you will get a token as shown in picture
[image: postman and jwt authentication]

Now use this token to get logged in user details, for example
**5.** make function in function.php

```
function checkloggedinuser()
{
$currentuserid_fromjwt = get_current_user_id();
print_r($currentuserid_fromjwt);
exit;
}

 add_action('rest_api_init', function ()
{
  register_rest_route( 'testone', 'loggedinuser',array(
  'methods' => 'POST',
  'callback' => 'checkloggedinuser'
  ));
});
```

**6.** Now again run this new url in postman or in app to get logged in user details.
https://example.com/wp-json/testone/loggedinuser
(replace example.com with your url)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have a faster and better solution to get the ID and more like the user avatar.

Just add this to your functions.php file:

```
/*
 * Insert some additional data to the JWT Auth plugin
 */
function jwt_auth_function($data, $user) { 
    $data['user_role'] = $user->roles; 
    $data['user_id'] = $user->ID; 
    $data['avatar']= get_avatar_url($user->ID);
    return $data; 
} 
add_filter( 'jwt_auth_token_before_dispatch', 'jwt_auth_function', 10, 2 );
```

Reference: [How to ger ID user via API](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-get-id-user/)

I hope that's helped

Answer (score -3):

Solved:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_api_hooks' );
function register_api_hooks() {
  register_rest_route(
    'custom-plugin', '/login/',
    array(
      'methods'  => 'POST',
      'callback' => 'login',
    )
  );
}
function login($request){
    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = $request["username"];
    $creds['user_password'] =  $request["password"];
    $creds['remember'] = true;
    $user = wp_signon( $creds, true );


    if ( is_wp_error($user) )
      echo $user->get_error_message();

    $id = $user->ID;
    $meta = get_user_meta($id);

    return $meta;
}
```

Comment: This is very insecure. You're sending the username and password openly in the URL.

Comment: Actually, I want to call it from android.

Comment: Doesn’t matter. Please read the link to the documentation I posted as a comment. There are proper, safer, ways to do this.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Would it be ok to use if we use POST instead of GET? The WP documentation link you gave actually was the first place I went to but it does not seem to cover anything about how to log in.

Comment: @Jacob, Post method data. So, its secure.

Comment: This may work for our use case, which is to have users of our server application transparently log in with their Wordpress credentials. We would essentially pass the details through server-to-server to WP to authenticate at the beginning of the session, and then cache the user details in our database. So we're only doing basic auth once per session via a trusted connection so the security issues are sidestepped, the client device only sends the credentials once. As an additional security measure, we'll require a shared secret key either in the header or as part of the request

Comment: Actually a better solution (for our use case) might be to use wp_authenticate rather than wp_signon because that then won't create a login session which could in theory be hijacked